# Find the closest value upper and lower from reference value in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to find the closest value upper and lower to an other value(price).
My code only show the closest value, no matter if it's up or down.

DF

```
           SYMBOL        price   gainddS8  gainddS7_5   gainddS7  gainddS6_5  \
102  1000SHIBUSDT     0.016049  -1.1       -0.1        1.5        2.12    
9         ADAUSDT     0.572700 -15.371514  -2.5       -1.0        2.497339   
24       ALGOUSDT     0.391300 -1.117796    0.5104497  14.091197   16.077897
```

Expected result

```
           SYMBOL        price  closestdown closestup
102  1000SHIBUSDT     0.016049 -0.1         1.5
9         ADAUSDT     0.572700 -1.0         2.497339
24       ALGOUSDT     0.391300  -1.117796   0.5104497
```

my code that find the closest value is:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='gain')
pos = df1.sub(df['price'], axis=0).abs().to_numpy().argmin(axis=1)
df['closestvalue'] = df1.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), pos]
```

the closest upper value will always be the cell next to the closest lower on the right if that can make it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Symbol": ["1000SHIBUSDT", "ADAUSDT", "ALGOUSDT"], 
     "Price": [0.016049, 0.572700, 0.391300],
     "gainddS8": [-1.1, -15.371514, -1.117796],
     "gainddS7_5": [-0.1, -2.5, 0.5104497],
     "gainddS7": [1.5, -1.0, 14.091197],
     "gainddS6_5": [2.12, 2.497339, 16.077897]
    }
)
```

You could do something like this:

```py
tmp = df.drop(columns=["Symbol"])
# Make sure that your columns have float data types, otherwise convert them to floats
df_new = df[["Symbol", "Price"]].assign(
    closestdown=tmp[tmp.apply(lambda x: x < tmp["Price"])].max(axis=1), 
    closestup=tmp[tmp.apply(lambda x: x > tmp["Price"])].min(axis=1)
)

print(df_new)
```

which results into

```py
    Symbol        Price     closestdown  closestup
0   1000SHIBUSDT  0.016049  -0.100000    1.500000
1   ADAUSDT       0.572700  -1.000000    2.497339
2   ALGOUSDT      0.391300  -1.117796    0.510450
```

Comment: i got an error :     result = libops.vec_compare(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
  File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 173, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_compare
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: how to print closestdown and closestup sir. thanks

Comment: @Oneboy, the error occurs because there are string value in some of your numeric columns. You have to convert them into floats first. Execute this line first: `df[df.drop(columns=["Symbol"]).columns] = df.drop(columns=["Symbol"]).astype(float)`. It converts all columns except of `Symbol` to floats.

Comment: @Oneboy, btw, you can print closestdown as follows: `print(df_new["closestdown"])`